# How can I get the synonymizer badge if I can't suggest synonyms - but my merge/synonym is accepted?

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

I suggested a merge + synonym on SF:

[TAG Merge : snapshot and snapshots](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3756/tag-merge-snapshot-and-snapshots)

It was completed - but I think I should get the badge for it - even though I can't create a synonym directly because of rep.

There are roughly 250+ synonyms on SF site, but only 37 synonymizer badges - I guess many synonymizers didn't get their badge because of this process.

So I suggest a way to delegate a synonymizer badge based on a suggestion in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Two sides for this.

On one hand, you do contribute to the site by suggesting such a thing so you do deserve some kind of reward.

On the other hand, badges are given as a reward on actual actions like posting, editing etc.

Many of the badges can't be awarded until the user reach certain reputation, most basic example is the Supporter badge that can be awarded only once the user reach enough reputation to cast upvote.

If you award the Synonymizer badge "manually", based only on suggestion on Meta site, you'll have to do the same for Taxonomist badge and likely more badges.

All in all, this sounds too complicated and I'm good enough with leaving those badges as they are meaning they can be awarded only to users above certain reputation threshold.

That said, as written above some reward is in place - maybe reputation points or something like that, but not a badge.